# When to use full backup or full backup and then differential backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

There is a SQL Server 2012 database that has the following configurations

1. Recovery mode : Simple
2. Backup Schedule : Full backup at 01:00 hours daily as well as differential database backup 13:00 hours daily

Once the differential backup of this database failed at 14:00 hours, the database then failed.

I need to restore this database and ensure the data loss is minimal.

Shall I choose

1. Restore the latest full backup, or
2. Restore the latest full backup, then restore the latest differential backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so since differential backup failed at 14:00, there is no latest differential backup file available. Therefore, the only sensible choice is Full Db Backup.

Answer (score 2):

Restore the latest full backup (using the `with norecovery` option) and the last good differential.